# How to write below target value as CSS selector in Webdriver to find element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

```
css=#lesson-basic-form_7 > div.row-fluid > div.span6 > fieldset.adminform > div.control-group.row-fluid > div.controls > #jform_name
```

This is the target value I got from Selenium IDE for an text input field. But not sure how to use this to find Element by cssselector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `#jform_name` is your input

```
By.cssSelector("input#jform_name");
```

you can also do this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("fieldset.adminform")).findElement(By.id("jform_name"));
```